# Why can't I cancel a repeating UILocalNotification?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

*Ciao, tout le monde.* In my Swift app, there is a `UILocalNotification` scheduled in a method that will be called after some time when the `UIViewController` is loaded, and it is repeating every hour (using `repeatInterval = .CalendarUnitHour`). I store this `UILocalNotification` instance in a private property in the `UIViewController` so that I can cancel it later on. When the user presses a button in the `UIViewController`, the action method will trigger the cancellation of the notification instance, by which I use this code (the code is also used in the `deinit` of the `UIViewController`:

```
if let notification = notificationProperty {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)
    notificationProperty = nil
}
```

I use a if-let statement here to prevent accidentally canceling a `nil` `UILocalNotification`. But even after it canceled the notification, the notification is still showing up every hour.

So why is it not cancelling properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notification that the system have is a copy of the one you are holding as a field. You can't cancel the one that you are holding since it is not a notification instance that is in the system.

You can cancel all the existing notifications by `cancelAllLocalNotifications` or find the one you want to cancel by iterating over all the existing instances by the `scheduledLocalNotifications` property.

Comment: Oh, that's a surprise! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: But does each repeated `UILocalNotification` posted counts as a separate notification? Or does the repeated `UILocalNotifications` counts as a group, so when you cancel it, all the posted ones get canceled?